# How to add a progress bar for webview

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, webviewclient

I'm new to app building... I tried to add a progress bar or a loading screen to a practice app but i wasn't successful.

Could you please help and show me how to do it and where to add it in the code.

Tab2.java:

```
package com.dan.test;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class Tab3Fragment extends Fragment {

    private WebView webView;
    private Bundle webViewBundle;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab2,
                container, false);

        webView = (WebView) ll.findViewById(R.id.tab2);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

   *public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
     // Activities and WebViews measure progress with different scales.
     // The progress meter will automatically disappear when we reach 100%
     activity.setProgress(progress * 1000);
   }*

        if (webViewBundle == null) {
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.loadUrl("https://www.youtube.com/");

        } else {
            webView.restoreState(webViewBundle);
        }

        return ll;

    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        webViewBundle = new Bundle();
        webView.saveState(webViewBundle);
    }
}
```

tab2.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tab2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">

*<ProgressBar android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center" android:id="@+id/progressBar1"/>*

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in advance,
Dan.

Comment: What did you try that did not work? We can help you with specific questions.. but asking to write code for you is something different and not what this site is for.

Comment: I tried to follow the instructions: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Comment: and i also tried to add this toTab2.xml: `<ProgressBar
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="center"
       android:id="@+id/progressBar1"/>  `

Comment: and adding the following below line 23: ` webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
   public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
     // Activities and WebViews measure progress with different scales.
     // The progress meter will automatically disappear when we reach 100%
     activity.setProgress(progress * 1000);
   }
 });`

Answer (score 1):

This is how I have been using it in the past.

```
webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {

        if (!mProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }

        mProgressDialog.setProgress(progress)

        if (progress == 100) {
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
});
```

Where `mProgressDialog` is a `Dialog` where I am showing the progress.